# How to use OpenZepplin DoubleEndedQueue library

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I'm trying to create a custom struct `mapping(uint => Queue)` to track my items with the ability to push and pop. I tried to use the [OpenZepplin DoubleEndedQueue](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#DoubleEndedQueue) but had an error when trying to call the methods. How can I use the datastructure? Thanks in advance

**This is how I called it:**

```
mapping(uint => DoubleEndedQueue.Bytes32Deque) private pendingAuctions;
pendingAuctions[key].push(Auction(_a));
```

**Error I'm getting:**

*Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct DoubleEndedQueue.Bytes32Deque storage ref*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

Instead of calling `instance.push()`.

I should be calling the library method like this:

```
DoubleEndedQueue.Bytes32Deque myQueue;
DoubleEndedQueue.push(myQueue, element);
```

[Source](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#DoubleEndedQueue-pushFront-struct-DoubleEndedQueue-Bytes32Deque-bytes32)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked lists the functions that are available on `DoubleEndedQueue.Bytes32Deque`. `push` isn't one of those functions, which is why you're getting the `Member "push" not found` error. If you're trying to add to the back of the queue, use the function `pushBack` documented on the docs. If you want to add to the front, use `pushFront` instead.